# Sending recorded packets

Tags: c#, send, packets

is there a library or a class that would allow me to record on going packets from my computer (which is done on tools such as ETHEREAL[WIRESHARK] & WPE PRO(if you happen to be a gamer). To then resend it on a loop.
I'm trying to make a service that would interact with my router on a timely basis.
Thanks ;).

Comment: What protocol are these packets associated with?

Comment: protocol ? Well, they go from my localhost to the router's IP :o
so tcp unless i'm wrong.

Comment: Not to be off-topic, but the dude who made WPE, Bradyok, is pretty good at making games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to resend packets from a .pcap file in a loop in C# you can use [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com).

See [Reading packets from a dump file in Pcap.Net tutorial](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20Tutorial%20-%20Handling%20offline%20dump%20files&referringTitle=Pcap.Net%20User%20Guide) to understand how to read the packets from the .pcap file and [Sending Packets in Pcap.Net tutorial](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20Tutorial%20-%20Sending%20Packets&referringTitle=Pcap.Net%20User%20Guide) to understand how to send the packets.

I hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Following clarification that this is for replay of TCP traffic I think your suggested approach is not suitable.

TCP is connection oriented and uses a random sequence number on establishing the connection so replaying the packets from an earlier session won't work.

Comment: Aight, i'm starting to get what you mean but just to clarify, in this case. Why can we replay some saved packets in order to cheat in some games, we use the same packet that does the same thing everytime. Some MMORPG Bots are built around that concept : Emulating player behavior using recorded packets for a set of actions. :/ ???

What i want to do with my router is make it Disconect from the internet and reconect a few seconds later in order to change IP's. I Was thinking my approach would work :(.

Answer (score 0):

With WPE PRO, you can send the same package multiple times, but (socket id) constantly changes as you close and open the game.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).